# xml getElementsByTagName returning null

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I'm trying to create a section of a web page which loops through reviews by storing the reviews in an xml file, using javascript to pull the data and set the loop parameters then html to display it. My codes are:

xml layout:

```
<reviewlist>
<review>
<author>Author Name Here</author>
<comment>Author Comment Here</comment>
</review> <!-- i have 4 reviews in total -->
</reviewlist>
```

javascript and html:

```js
function reviews() {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {                                  
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");       
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../xml/Reviews.xml");
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("reviewlist")[0];   //pull all 'review' elements into a string
    var tot = x.childNodes.length[0];                   //pull the number of 'review' elements as an Int. This shows the total number of reviews to cycle through
    var i = 0;                                          //a counter which will be used to identify which review number to display

    var content = "current review no." + i;
    var author = "total reviews: " + tot;
    document.getElementById('review').innerHTML = content;
    document.getElementById('reviewer').innerHTML = author;

    var id = setInterval(revolve, 10000); //each time the function repeats, check that the counter is a lower number than the total number of reviews. If true, show the current review no and how many reviews there are in total.
    function revolve() {
        if (i << tot) {
            content = "current review no. " + i;
            author = "total reviews: " + tot;
            i++;
        } else {                         //when the counter and the total reviews variables are equal, reset counter to 0 and loop through the reviews again
            content = "current review no. " + i;
            author = "total reviews: " + tot;
            i = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('review').innerHTML = content;
        document.getElementById('reviewer').innerHTML = author;
    }
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="review" id="review" style="top:0;"></blockquote>
<p class="reviewer" id="reviewer" style="bottom:0;right:0;"></p>
```

In my web developer I'm getting the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null' but I can't see where I've gone wrong. What can I do to resolve this error and eventually have the tot variable return 4 (the numbers of reviews in my XML file)?

Comment: You're aware `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323?

Comment: *facepalm* I'm an idiot. Think I should go and do something else for a bit and let my brain reset. Thank you for setting me right though!